# Clearing All ComboBoxes method

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am trying to create a method that will clear all of the `ComboBoxes` on my window. This is what I have tried so far:

```
private void ClearAllComboboxes(ComboBox cmb)
{
    cmb.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

And then I call the method like below, but I can only insert one `ComboBox` to clear at a time.

```
private void btnClearAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ClearAllComboboxes(cmbBarlocks);
}
```

So what I am trying to do is clear all of the comboboxes with as little coding as possible. Can someone please tell me how and what would be the best possible way to do this? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using MVVM and you have SelectedItem property for every combobox in your viewmodel.
In viewmodel, you can just set SelectedItem=null for each combobox.
It will clear your combobox selection.

If you are not using MVVM, then you can use following code in code behind:

```
private void ClearAllComboboxes()
    {
        List<ComboBox> comboBoxes = new List<ComboBox>();

        GetLogicalChildCollection<ComboBox>(container, comboBoxes);

        comboBoxes.ForEach(combobox => combobox.SelectedIndex = -1);
    }

    private static void GetLogicalChildCollection<T>(DependencyObject parent,List<T> logicalCollection) where T : DependencyObject
    {

        var children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent);
        foreach (object child in children)
        {
            if (child is DependencyObject)
            {
                DependencyObject depChild = child as DependencyObject;
                if (child is T)
                {
                    logicalCollection.Add(child as T);
                }
                GetLogicalChildCollection(depChild, logicalCollection);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment man! :D I am getting the error "_Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type argument_"

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact line

Comment: Please check if you have added reference to System.Collections.Generic. also i have edited answer see if it resolves your error. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your handler try this, it worked when I had a similar issue with ListBox

```
void ClearCombos(params ComboxBox[] boxes)
{
foreach(var box in boxes)
box.ItemsSource = null;
}
```

and call it ClearCombos(x,y,z); where x,y,z are the boxes you want to clear

Comment: How would this help me clear all of my ComboBoxes at once?

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume All your `comboboxes` are inside a container(let it be `stackPanel`), the you can set selected index to -1 for all of them using the following snippet:

```
  foreach (Control ctrl in stkContainer.Children)
            {
                if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox))
                {
                    ComboBox cbo = ctrl as ComboBox;
                    ClearAllComboboxes(cbo);
                }
            }
```

If you want to clear the combobox means you have to re-define your method signature as:

```
private void ClearAllComboboxes(ComboBox cmb)
{
   cmb.Items.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) I'm getting the error with your coding: _Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.Control'._?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ClearInputs(Page.Controls);
        }

        //For Clear All Control Values
        void ClearInputs(ControlCollection ctrls)
        {
         foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
            {
               if (ctrl is ComboBox )
                    ((ComboBox )ctrl).ClearSelection();

                ClearInputs(ctrl.Controls);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Where do I get the `ControlCollection`? Is this for WPF or WinForms? :)